# How could I make this figure?

Tags: graphics

[image]

How can I make this figure, haven't really used Tikz or other tools yet. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way might be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}
\rightarrow
\begin{array}{c}
000\\
111
\end{array}
\rightarrow\Gamma\rightarrow
\begin{array}{c}
000\\
001\\
010\\
100\\
011\\
101\\
110\\
111
\end{array}
\rightarrow
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Another simple proposal using `tikz-cd` package (or `xy` package). The lenghts of the arrows can be increase or decrease.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\begin{matrix} 0\\ 1 \end{matrix} \arrow[r] & \begin{matrix} 000\\ 111 \end{matrix} \arrow[r] & \mathit{\Gamma} \arrow[r] & \begin{matrix} 000\\ 001\\ 010\\ 100\\ 011\\ 101\\ 110\\ 111 \end{matrix} \arrow[r] & \begin{matrix} 0\\ 1 \end{matrix}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2020/12/13:** I add the code with `xy` package; it is possible to see that the structure of the code is very closer than `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ {\begin{matrix} 0\\ 1 \end{matrix}} \ar[r] & {\begin{matrix} 000\\ 111 \end{matrix}} \ar[r] &  \Gamma \ar[r]& {\begin{matrix} 000\\ 001\\ 010\\ 100\\ 011\\ 101\\ 110\\ 111 \end{matrix}}\ar[r] & {\begin{matrix} 0\\ 1 \end{matrix}}}

\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]